# recommended number of puma threads for rails apps on google app engine ruby standard environment?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, google-app-engine

I know the Google App Engine Standard Ruby 2.55 runtime has some restrictions when it comes to concurrency. With that in mind, is there an ideal number of Puma threads to use when deploying a Rails app to App Engine Standard?

Edit: is it just as much as memory will allow on whatever instance type you are using, or is it better to always just use one thread with App Engine Standard and let instance numbers do their thing.

Comment: Side note: in my case I'm hacking an existing flex environment rails app into working on standard, preferably on F1 instances even though F2 is recommended (since F1 is in the daily free tier).

Comment: I would argue that this depends highly on your specific application. How big is the application? How much memory does the app consumer after running for several hours? How much traffic does the application get? Is the application IO or compute-heavy?

Comment: Fair enough. I'm basically looking for someone to say "yes, it's OK to have more than one thread on app engine standard" or "no, you should use only one thread per instance and let instances take care of concurrency because of X performance reason". I'll revise the question

Comment: I think the question is too broad. As @spickermann pointed out, the environment affects it and we don't know your environment. You want us to give you a concise, definitive answer, and we can't do it unless we know a lot more. SO is about concise and definitive, not opinions or guesses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot of experimenting with 10+ client rails apps, here is what I came up with:

1. In general, app engine standard doesn't need any special consideration when it comes to threading, despite the warnings in the docs.
2. For most rails apps, 2-5 threads is ideal, depending on memory usage and instance size
3. Small rails apps can fit on an F1 instance, larger (most) apps need at least an F2
4. Lowering the number of threads decreases memory usage by a moderate amount, but if things are ridiculously slow, you need to increase instance size

Hope this helps anyone in a similar situation.